# how to display G map by repeater and markers from database

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps

I want to display google map inside repeater from database values comes, i searched on google and reached to this result but not working with me i don't know if it have something missing or not can you help me please.

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal1"></asp:Literal>
  
     <script type="text/javascript">
       
        var markers = [
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
                 {

                "title": '<%# Eval("City") %>',
                 "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
                 "lng": '<%# Eval("Longitude") %>'
                
             }
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        ,
    </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    ];

    </script>
    </body>
```

Here my code behind aspx.cs,

```
 public class Markers
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
}


void GetData(string strRsult)
{
    XmlDataDocument xmlDataDoc = new XmlDataDocument();
    xmlDataDoc.LoadXml(strRsult);

    Literal1.Text = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">var markers = [";

    foreach (XmlNode n in xmlDataDoc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("Property"))
    {
        if (n.HasChildNodes)
        {
          List<Markers> markers = new List<Markers>();
            foreach (XmlNode childNode in n)
            {
                if (childNode.Name == "GEOData")
                {
                    Literal1.Text += "title: '" + childNode.Attributes["City"].Value + "', lat: '" + childNode.Attributes["Longitude"].Value + "', lng: '" + childNode.Attributes["Latitude"].Value + "'}";
                }

            }

            Literal1.Text += "];</script>";

        }

    }
```

```html
XML file

- <AVSearch_PropertyDetails RequestedCurrency="EUR">
- <Property IDHotel="10000" PropertyCode="10000" Hotelname="REZ:Online HOTEL" StarCategory="0" ImageIdentifier="RHN_10000" NumberOfRooms="80" CheckinTime="00:00" CheckoutTime="23:59" Email="info@r-h-n.com" Status="0" StatusInfo="">
- <GEOData CountryCode="DE" CountryName="Germany" City="Duesseldorf" IDCity="32" Zip="40472" Street="Wanheimer Street 45" Longitude="6.7932130" Latitude="51.2871870">
- <Distances>
  <Distance Type="1" Distance="0.50" /> 
  <Distance Type="2" Distance="1.81" /> 
  </Distances>
  </GEOData>
- <Descriptions>
  <Description IDLanguage="4" IDType="1" Text="This is the test hotel used for testing and debugging purposes only. Please do not book this hotel." /> 
  <Description IDLanguage="4" IDType="4" Text="This is a testhotel" /> 
  <Description IDLanguage="4" IDType="3" Text="Terms & conditions EN" /> 
  </Descriptions>
`
```

Comment: Did you register the script properly on page load? see this example, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/529841/Running-a-client-side-script-from-server-side-code

Comment: @ahmeaad, what you want to do exactly?

Comment: @cracker i want to display google-map get the values from database

Comment: take a literal in site for loop add all the values to in and pass it to control => Literal1.Text += "title: '" + childNode.Attributes["City"].Value + "', lat: '" + childNode.Attributes["Longitude"].Value + "', lng: '" + childNode.Attributes["Latitude"].Value + "'}"; it is not valid array it will not work

Comment: @cracker ok what can i do to work

Comment: @ahmeaad, use this => http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/175557/Plot-Path-using-Google-Maps-JavaScript-API

Comment: @cracker i will give you this link to see something i want to display the map after button click not on pageload event sory www.myhotels24.eu/fibe.aspx

Comment: use the same for button click that's all

Answer (score 0):

Download Google Map DLL in your project from codeplex [GoogleMapControl](http://googlemap.codeplex.com/).

Register DLL in your page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Artem.Google" Namespace="Artem.Google.UI" TagPrefix="artem" %>
```

Here is the steps to create Google Map dynamically in repeater control.

First download `Artem.Google.dll` from [this link](http://googlemap.codeplex.com/releases/view/95924) and put down DLL in `bin` folder.

**ASPX Page Code:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="GmapRepeater.aspx.cs" Inherits="GmapRepeater" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <%@ Register Assembly="Artem.Google" Namespace="Artem.Google.UI" TagPrefix="artem" %>

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
 <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptMarkers_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <artem:GoogleMap ID="GMap" runat="server"></artem:GoogleMap>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</div>
</form>
```

**ASPX.CS Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Artem.Google.UI;

 public partial class GmapRepeater : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GetData();
    }
}
protected void rptMarkers_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Markers loData = (Markers)e.Item.DataItem;
        GoogleMap GMap = (GoogleMap)e.Item.FindControl("GMap");

        GMap.MapType = Artem.Google.UI.MapType.Roadmap;
        GMap.ApiVersion = "v2";
        GMap.Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(loData.Latitude);
        GMap.Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(loData.Longitude);
        GMap.Zoom = 18;
        GMap.EnableMapTypeControl = false;
        GMap.Height = 200;
        GMap.Width = 195;

        Marker loMarker = new Marker();
        loMarker.Position.Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(loData.Latitude);
        loMarker.Position.Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(loData.Longitude);
        loMarker.Clickable = true;
        loMarker.Info = "Marker Information";
        loMarker.Title = "Title of your Marker";
        loMarker.Visible = true;

        GMap.Markers.Add(loMarker);
    }
}
 private void GetData()
{
    XmlDataDocument xmlDataDoc = new XmlDataDocument();
    xmlDataDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Files/XMLFile.xml"));
    List<Markers> markers = new List<Markers>();

    foreach (XmlNode n in xmlDataDoc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("Property"))
    {
        if (n.HasChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode childNode in n)
            {
                if (childNode.Name == "GEOData")
                {
                    Markers loObj = new Markers();
                    loObj.City = Convert.ToString(childNode.Attributes["City"].Value);
                    loObj.Longitude = Convert.ToString(childNode.Attributes["Longitude"].Value);
                    loObj.Latitude = Convert.ToString(childNode.Attributes["Latitude"].Value);
                    markers.Add(loObj);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (markers != null && markers.Count > 0)
    {
        rptMarkers.DataSource = markers;
        rptMarkers.DataBind();
    }
}
}
```

**Markers Entity Class:**

```
public class Markers
{
     public string City { get; set; }
     public string Latitude { get; set; }
     public string Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: i want it with repeater

Comment: I have updated my answer and paste your whole my web page. Just provide your database data in Page_Load event to repeater data source.

Comment: ok that's good but i want to take lat and long from database not static like that.

Comment: Can you please show me code how do you get latitude/longitude from database?? so I can give you some more hint to solve your problem. :)

Comment: in my example their in the question you can check it :)

Comment: You are fetching data from XML file. right?? Can you show me structure of XML file??

Comment: Do you have list of hotels in this XML file OR you have one XML file for 1 hotel??

Comment: i have one xml file only

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer. I make it Latitude/Longitude dynamically, taking from XML file. Please check  it now.

Comment: thank's , i checked it now and try your code but the gmap not display yet.

Comment: i want remove the repeater now and make it without it how can i make it

Comment: i think the problem when databind() call the Gmap control cannot find it or what i think i am not sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75806/discussion-between-dexterity-and-ahmeaad).